# mysql update statement

Tags: mysql

I have this statement which calls insert data to table "users" when table "users" already has data. I need to update the count of users every time i load this script. My update statement isn't working.

Any clue? No update happened and the old numbers still exist.

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('%s','%s',%s)",
                mysql_real_escape_string($user['username']),
                mysql_real_escape_string($user['name']),
                mysql_real_escape_string($user['countusers']),
            $res = mysql_query($query);
            $query = "UPDATE users (username, name, countuser) VALUES ('$username',        '$name', '$countuser')";
            $res = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Perl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should do what you're looking for if `username` is a primary or unique key. More information in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you check whether the user already exists.

Also in the insert query you use:

```
$user['username'], $user['name'] and $user['countuser'];
```

but in the update query you do:

```
$username, $name and $countuser
```